# how to turn on search suggestions programatically in IE9

Tags: internet-explorer, registry

I implemented and added my own search provider in IE9, the search suggestions is turned on when I click on the manage add-on menu. But when I typed a word on the address bar, the drop down menu didn't show any suggestion, instead it said "turn on suggestions, send keystrokes to ..." If I click on that, then the search suggestion came. I am wondering why. I assume if it showed enabled from the manage add on menu, user don't need to show it again. Is this some kind of bug in IE9 or I am missing something? Anyone can tell me what registry key related to this? Thanks,